# ISO 8601 date format in HAproxy log

Tags: haproxy, iso8601

Is it possible to change the date format of `%t` in HAproxy 2.6 logs? By default it appears as `17/May/2023:09:17:11.526` however I would prefer an ISO 8601-like date string.

Based on the [template case](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/c8a7bb16b7f0511bfdbf1ef3b03e369d518e8fac/src/log.c#L2236) and the [date2str_log](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/c8a7bb16b7f0511bfdbf1ef3b03e369d518e8fac/src/tools.c#L3477) implementation, it looks like the format is hard-coded.

Are there alternative ways to get the accepted date with millisecond resolution in an arbitrary format?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead send logs to your favourite syslog or logger to add timestamps the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy has the [log configuration setting](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#3.1-log). With `format iso`, every log is prefixed with an ISO 8601 timestamp. However, this does not offer nuanced timestamps like time of connect, time of accept, time of first byte, ...